# Getting error “PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Zend\Uri\Exception\InvalidUriPartException” on AWS server

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, php7, zend-framework

I am getting following error in error_log after moving the site (developed in Magento ver. 2.3.2) on new server (AWS Server):

> PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Zend\Uri\Exception\InvalidUriPartException:
>   Host "[IP ADDRESS]" is not valid or is not accepted by Zend\Uri\Http
>   in /public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-uri/src/Uri.php:746

I feel that it's a server level issue. 
Anyone have idea how to fix this error?

Comment: is it magento related build ?

Comment: Yes, but I checked the file but didn't found any code level issue. That's why I raised this issue here.

Comment: Check if php version is compatible with magento.

Comment: @SukhjinderSingh I checked this by change the php version but still getting same error. I am using PHP 7.2

Comment: `[IP ADDRESS]` is the real return or you changed it?

Comment: Here showing server local IP address. I changed it.

Comment: I'm seeing 127.0.0.1 in my logs. Did you find out where the problem is?